# Marklogic - How to rollback document

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am a newbie to marklogic. How do I rollback a document I deleted.  I use the function `xdmp:rollback()` from https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:rollback. but I could not see a document restore back to database.  Thanks in advance.

```
xdmp:document-delete("/data/edu/GMU.xml"),
xdmp:rollback()
```

Comment: Did you delete the document and execute rollback in the same transaction the first time it was deleted? Because you can't rollback a transaction that's already committed. There is a possibility it still exists in a data structure in the database, but probably not if a lot of time has passed since you deleted.

Answer (score 2):

In your example code you never actually committed the document (because the full statement never concluded successfully) and so you don't need to do a rollback.  You just need to prevent the statement from succeeding by, for example, generating an `fn:error()` to fail the entire statement and then all pending changes in the statement will never be committed.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Understanding Transactions in MarkLogic Server](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions#chapter).